# How to convert String to List without using eval() in Python

Tags: python

I will like to convert the following string to a list without using eval in python.

```
"[['age', '>=', 30], ['age', '<', 36]]"
```

The output should be like this:

```
['age', '>=', 30] >> list position -[0] 
['age', '<', 36]  >> list position -[1]
```

Comment: "not allow to import"  Is that a limitation imposed by a homework assignment or from a tool you're trying to use (like some scriptable application that wants a python script?).  Either way, please update your question to reflect your exact requirements.

Answer (score 9):

Try `ast.literal_eval()`:

```
import ast
x = ast.literal_eval("[['age', '>=', 30], ['age', '<', 36]]")
print x
print type(x)
```

Running this script displays:

```
[['age', '>=', 30], ['age', '<', 36]]
<type 'list'>
```

The `ast.literal_eval()` is a a safe `eval()` that only evaluates literals such as strings, lists, tuples, numbers, and booleans.

Source: http://docs.python.org/dev/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval

Comment: Thanks Impossibility,

Comment: Thanks Impossibility,
based on our application we can't used python regex and ast features. Because of our application not allow to import any classes as well as not allow to write function.

thanks