# extract a list within a string sequence

Tags: python, list

I have a sequence of string which has a python list within it. It looks like this

```
"['How', 'Quebec', 'nationalists', 'see', 'province', 'nation', '1960s?']"
```

How can I can retrieve the string enclosed by [] as the list data type of python?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert string representation of list to list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894269/convert-string-representation-of-list-to-list)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to conver String to List withou using eval(Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19418566/how-to-conver-string-to-list-withou-using-evalpython)

Comment: Is it sure that the string only contains the list or may it contain something else too? I.e., is the following possible: `"This is my list ['a', 'b', 'c']. It's a beautiful list.`?

Answer (score 2):

Use a regular expression to extract the list:

```
re.findall("\'(.*?)\'",st)

#['How', 'Quebec', 'nationalists', 'see', 'province', 'nation', '1960s?']
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) function from the standard library:

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> literal_eval("['How', 'Quebec', 'nationalists', 'see', 'province', 'nation', '1960s?']")
['How', 'Quebec', 'nationalists', 'see', 'province', 'nation', '1960s?']
```

This is way more safe than using `eval` directly ([source](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html)).

Answer (score 1):

Use python's `eval` function to evaluate the string and get a list

```
>>> x = "['How', 'Quebec', 'nationalists', 'see', 'province', 'nation', '1960s?']"
>>> eval(x)
['How', 'Quebec', 'nationalists', 'see', 'province', 'nation', '1960s?']
>>> type(eval(x))
<class 'list'>
```

***NOTE:***

`eval` is dangerous in case you are exposing the code to open world such as a website or an api. `eval` executes in global namespace and hence could be dangerous.

Example:
`eval(os.listdir())` gives all files and folder in working directory.

Comment: dont use eval, use ast.literal_eval instead

Comment: That answer is dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve your desired result using string operations and slicing:

```
string = "['How', 'Quebec', 'nationalists', 'see', 'province', 'nation', '1960s?']"
wordList = list(map(lambda elem: elem.replace('\'','') ,string[1:-1].split(', ')))
print(wordList)
```

Output:

```
['How', 'Quebec', 'nationalists', 'see', 'province', 'nation', '1960s?']
```